# How to convert Excel's IF function number result to currency?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following if function:
=IF(B6>=0, "100","0")
and I would like to convert the result(s) to currency ($) and work with them.

I have tried the following: 
=IF(B6>=0, "$100","$0")
and it gave back the dollar sign, however, it was not an actual currency cell after all and I could not work with it.

The result should be: either $100 or $0 but should be in currency.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to format the cell to currency, you can also drop the quotations

```
=IF(B6>=0,100,0)
```

[image]

Comment: You welcome :), please if this answered your question consider marking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Text function is another way to format information in cells.

```
=IF(B6>=0,TEXT( 100,"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"))
```